Combining two Pandas dataframe with unequal number of columns (superset)
I have below code:
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'y':[7,8,9]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'b':[10,11,12],'x':[13,14,15],'y':[16,17,18]})
pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([df1, df2]), columns=df1.columns)

Above code generates error. I expect that final dataframe will be all columns from df1 and df2. Therefore will be missing values as column names are different.
Is there any way to achieve this?

pd.concatenate? Could you give the expected output so we should guess less what you want to obtain?

"Above code generates error." - would you mind telling us what error it generates? With 3k of reputation you should have seen questions containing expected and actual behavior.

IIUC use:
df = pd.concat([df1.set_axis(range(len(df1.columns)), axis=1),
                df2.set_axis(range(len(df2.columns)), axis=1)])
print (df)
    0   1     2
0   1   7   NaN
1   2   8   NaN
2   3   9   NaN
0  10  13  16.0
1  11  14  17.0
2  12  15  18.0

Or maybe:
df = pd.concat([df1,df2])
print (df)
     a   y     b     x
0  1.0   7   NaN   NaN
1  2.0   8   NaN   NaN
2  3.0   9   NaN   NaN
0  NaN  16  10.0  13.0
1  NaN  17  11.0  14.0
2  NaN  18  12.0  15.0

